# Error message on login form uses browser default font

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, login

When you login to a StackExchange site (in this case, SO) and make a mistake with your login details, an error message appears.

However, it looks like the proper styling has not been applied to the font, and it instead uses the browser default font (in this case, Times New Roman):

[image: Error message is using times new roman]